# Saving Each Token in Separate row in Database

Tags: mysql, token

I am trying to save each string token in separate row in database, so that i can compare it with other string Tokens.

I am using PHP explode function and my syntax is:

```
<?php
$someWords = "Please don't, blow me to pieces."; 

$wordChunks = explode(" ", $someWords);
for($i = 0; $i < count($wordChunks); $i++){
echo "Piece $i = $wordChunks[$i] <br />";

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","","","test");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

  $sql="INSERT INTO TableName (file1) VALUES ('$wordChunks')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added successfully";

    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

It gives this output

[image: it save the tokens in array not in string tokens]

And i want this output

[[image: I want that output[2]]

Comment: Use `$sql = "INSERT INTO TableName (file1) VALUES ('$wordChunks[$i]')";`.

Comment: @D4V1D

It works fine but when i use DON'T in the string variable it give error:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't,')' at line 1

How can i solve that, my database file type is varchar(100)

Comment: Can you make what you say clearer?

Comment: When i use quotation sign (') in sentence like i have used in the string "Please don't, blow me to pieces." it gives error

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't,')' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL `mysqli_real_escape_string` function to escape the string before including it in the query:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO TableName (file1) VALUES ('.mysqli_real_escape_string($wordChunks[$i]).')';
```

Comment: It says:
string 'Please don't blow me to pieces.' (length=31)

My database field type is varchar